# Open txt file through Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm wondering how to open a file through a Tkinter GUI, example having a button in your interface that opens a .txt file. It doesn't matter if it loads into a textbox or if it opens in the text-editor just want it to open. Preferably to open in the text-editor.

```
def openInstruktion():
    f= open("instruktioner.txt")

instruktionBtn = Button(root, text='Spelinstruktioner', command=openInstruktion)
instruktionBtn.grid(row=6, column=0)
```

I've searched the web for some answer but most people use the menubar. I want it to open through the button posted above.

Comment: Do you mean in your system's default text editor?

Comment: You should be able to open a text file in your system's default text editor with `os.startfile(filepath)` or `os.system(filepath)`.

Comment: yes! Exactly, It's for a game with instructions, if they klick the button the default systems editor opens with the file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open the file with the default program, you could use the os module:

```
def openInstruktion():
    from os import startfile
    startfile("c:\\path\\to\\file")

instruktionBtn = Button(root, text='Spelinstruktioner', command=openInstruktion)
instruktionBtn.grid(row=6, column=0)
```

or, if you want to open it with a specific program, try the subprocess module:

```
def openInstruktion():
    from subprocess import call
    call("notepad c:\\path\\to\\file")

instruktionBtn = Button(root, text='Spelinstruktioner', command=openInstruktion)
instruktionBtn.grid(row=6, column=0)
```

If you want to open it in a textbox however, you could do something like this:

```
file = open("c:\\path\\to\\file").read()
textbox.insert(0.0, file)
```

Your best bet would probably be to open it in the default editor (opening it with a different program may not be what people want and opening it in a textbox has poor graphics).

Answer (score 2):

So if you want to do something to the file the operations will happen in function `openInstruktion`.

```
def openInstrucktion():
    f= open("instruktioner.txt")
    #t is a Text widget
    t.insert(1.0, f.read())
```

Or if you want to open it with an editor:

```
def openInstrucktion():
    os.system('emacs instrucktioner.txt')
```

Comment: Open it for what? If just post the content to a textbox, it is no hard. Or use the default editor to open it? @andrejcurcic

Comment: I have no other meanings. I just don't understand the question clearly. I will update my answer. :)@andrejcurcic

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think this time it is right. @andrejcurcic

Comment: I get the error message, 

File "/Users/andrej/Documents/mathgame.py", line 57, in openInstruktion
    f= open("instruktioner.txt")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'instruktioner.txt'

Comment: Since you directly use `instruktioner.txt` with no path, you have to execute the script in the dir the `instruktioner.txt` in.@andrejcurcic

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the file in the default editor
(it always best to use the default one only)

```
def openInstrucktion():
    os.system('start " " instruktioner.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def help():
    readme = "F:\\yourpath\\readme.txt"
    os.startfile(readme)
```

just use this function , but first do `import os` at the top..

Answer (score 0):

```
  from tkinter import filedialog

  tf = filedialog.askopenfilename(
     initialdir="C:/", #insert your own path
     title="Open Text file", 
     filetypes=(("TextFiles", "*.text"),)
    )
 # tf: file full path
 with open(tf) as f:
        for l in f:
           print(l)
```